# Cannot to delete the GameObject

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

I put the all GameObjects in scene under a list. the following is function used in the shelf.cs to delete the gameobjects. I assign the function to a button, so that it takes input value and find which Gameobject has lesser value than input. Then delete. The problem is whenever I click the button in the game preview, it won't delete the gameobjects. There are no warnings. I debug whether it receives all input, and it did. just not deleting the GameObjects.

Why?

```
public void Process(){
    int user_apple,user_lemon,user_watermelon;

    user_apple = int.Parse (input_apple.text);
    user_lemon = int.Parse (input_lemon.text);
    user_watermelon = int.Parse (input_watermelon.text);

    Debug.Log (user_apple+" "+user_lemon+" "+user_watermelon);

    for(int i = players.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {   if(players[i].name == "Lemon")
        {
            if(players[i].GetComponent<Apple>().weight <= user_apple)
            {   Debug.Log ("wat u want");
                Destroy(players[i]);
            }players.RemoveAt(i);

        }
    }
}
```

---

if i were to put it like this,

```
public void Process(){
    int user_apple,user_lemon,user_watermelon;

    user_apple = int.Parse (input_apple.text);
    user_lemon = int.Parse (input_lemon.text);
    user_watermelon = int.Parse (input_watermelon.text);

    Debug.Log (user_apple+" "+user_lemon+" "+user_watermelon);
    if(players[2].GetComponent<Lemon>().weight <= user_apple)
    {   Destroy(players[2]);
        players.RemoveAt(2);
    }
}
```

it will have errors like below

```
FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs:629)
Basket.Process () (at Assets/scripts/Basket.cs:77)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:110)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:575)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:717)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Comment: generally you SHOULD NOT use underscores in variables.  So, it should be  userApple, userLemon and so on.  you need to carefully and properly format your code.  you can ***never, ever*** make software unless you are absolutely fanatical about formatting.

Comment: BTW note that it's not so easy to parse text to ints or floats.  Essentially, you can't use "Parse".  You have to use TryParse.  it takes quite a bit of work and you'll need an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the right solution try calling a co-routine from the Process Function and yield the loop so it runs everyframe.

Comment: so i have to call this function into another function of another class to make it work? is there an example of how to do this?

Comment: no ! now use like this 
void Process(){  startCourotiune(CProcess) ; }
ienumerator CProcess(){   loop with yeild statemnet    }
mind the syntax and learn about coroutines and how they help run code frame by frame

Comment: wat does these mean? `The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(System.Collections.IEnumerator)' has some invalid arguments-- error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `method group' expression to type `System.Collections.IEnumerator' --error CS0161: `Basket.CProcess()': not all code paths return a value'

Comment: In a coroutine you need a yield statement , so use yield return 0 in your for loop and yes you can even pass arguments from the process function to your coroutine

Comment: hi @LumbusterTick - if you're having problems like that it's because of a racetrack condition where you're incorrectly destroying objects or components without considering the frame.  there's no reason at all a loop "won't work" from a button or anywhere else.

Comment: not that it matters but to skip a frame, you should  yield return null, not zero

Comment: beside that there's also because i forgot to put () behind Cprocess. lol thank you very much

Comment: hi @whoami it's a shame this answer is Ticked because while a helpful attempt it is not, in fact, correct.  Loops work perfectly on buttons.  hopefully this does not confuse any future googlers who land here

Comment: hi bra, i've never been angry in my life!  i just said, **"Loops work perfectly on buttons"**  ciao

Comment: @Fattie you are correct on this issue and I made a mistake. upvoted. I am deleting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to recap what Joe Blow said: there is no reason why this for loop should not work since it is totally independant of frames/time.

This little example works perfectly fine:
The script `ScriptHolder` is assigned to an empty gameobject (see screen below) and looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ScriptHolder: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> theGameObjects;

    public void TheButtonFunction(int weight)
    {
        for(int i = theGameObjects.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(theGameObjects[i].GetComponent<TheObject>().objectWeight <= weight)
            {
                Destroy(theGameObjects[i]);
                theGameObjects.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All gameobjects were dragged into the public list.

[image]

The script for the gameobjects looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TheObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string objectName = "";
    public int objectWeight = 0;
}
```

All `GameObject_A` are named `A` and have a weight of `10` (done in the inspector), `GameObject_B` are `B` with a weight of `15` and `GameObject_C` are `C` with a weight of `20`. Columns are A to C from left to right.

The button calls the function from above with a value of `15`.
[image]

When I click the button, the left and the middle columns of gameobjects are deleted from the scene and from the list - no problem whatsoever.